# WTForms dynamic form with 2 types of fields

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to create a dynamic form with two types of fields using WTForms.
I have one class CustomersQuestionFields from which I want to show the questions and save the answers in another class called CustomerQuestions.
This is their structure:

```
**class CustomerQuestionFields:**
id
description
label

**class CustomerQuestions:**
id
customer_question_fields_id
customer_id
value
description
```

The idea is to fill in CustomerQuestionFields with text and pull them as labels on value and description on CustomerQuestions.
Values is RadioField and description is TextAreaField.

I've tried creating a dictionary and I successfully get the fields, show them and save the data, but the problem is that I want to connect one value with one description.

The current (sorted) dictionary that I'm getting is:

```
[{description_1 : WTFormsTextAreaField}, {description_10: WTFormsTextAreaField}, {description_2: WTFormsTextAreaField},..., {value_1: WTFormsRadioField}, {value_10: WTFormsRadioField}, {value_2: WTFormsradioField}, ...}]
```

and when I try to show this in template first description fields are shown, and then value fields.

Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to paste the code for the dictionary:

```
 def create_question_form_class(questions):
     form_fields = []

     for q in questions:
         field_id = 'value_{}' + str(q.id)
         form_fields[field_id] = RadioField(q.description, choices = [('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Yes')], default="Select")

         field_id = 'description_'+ str(q.id)
         form_fields[field_id] = TextAreaField()

    return type('CustomerQuestions', (Form,), form_fields)
```

Comment: What value are you trying to connect to what description? Also, what does connect mean?

Comment: I want one TextAreaField with one RadioField. The TextAreaField should have as label the description from CustomerQuestionFields and the RadioFiled should have as label the label field from CustomerQuestionFields. 
So one TextAreaField and one RadioField represent one question. 
The problem that I'm having is definitely the rendering of the fields because of the structure of the dictionary.

Comment: I only came across examples with one dynamic field of one type, but not with two different types of fields.